# Solr suggester not returning numbers

Tags: solr

This is the fieldType used by the Solr suggester's queryAnalyzer, and by the field used by the Suggester itself.

```
<fieldType name="the_suggest_type" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" omitNorms="true">
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

- I verified that the field used by the suggester itself has the values that start with numbers like "34-ab", "676-32" etc
- `http://localhost:1234/solr/select/?qt=/suggest&q=34` returns no results.
- I'm using org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester

Comment: Are you using spellcheck.q? Do you have the queryAnalyzerFieldType set in solrconfig.xml?

Comment: Please show your SpellCheckComponent configuration in solrconfig.xml

Comment: Since it was a year ago, now I dont have code anymore. This guys seems to have a [similar problem](http://grokbase.com/t/lucene/solr-user/12475fgdy6/suggester-not-working-for-digit-starting-terms) Steps to reproduce are : Use Suggester, and index terms that start with number and test.